# $location.path() returns wrong value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular application which is divided into multiple smaller applications. The system works pretty easy: the user logs in, then he can select which subapplication he wants to use.

I'd like to display the name of the application in the header. In the `.run`, I have this on the `$rootscope`. The reason I put it here is simple: the user can use the application normally, but he can also decide just to use F5 to refresh the page. This way, I can decide by the URL which application the user is running.

```
$rootScope.$on( '$stateChangeStart', function(e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
               // bunch of other code
                            var path = $location.path();
                            console.log($location);
                            if (path.indexOf("pricelist") > -1) {
                                authentication.setApplication("PRICELIST");
                            } else {
                                authentication.setApplication("HUB");
                            }
                            $state.go(toState, toParams);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
```

If the URL contains "pricelist", it should set the application name to "PRICELIST". However, this statement returns false and so it sets the wrong name.

After debugging, I've noticed something weird in `$location`:
[image: console.log of $location]

As you see, there are two `$$path`: one with the correct URL and one with just `/`. The correct one is the one containing `/pricelist`, but `$location.path()` seems to return the wrong one.

What is happening here? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: when you made your console.log($location) the path was "/" and when you open it it's a live version of the object so between the two it has changed. you'r using stateChangeStart so the change hasn't been made yet that's why

Comment: But why does $location also contain the correct URL?

Comment: it doesn't that your console working like that, the first line is static it can't change and it is being displayed at stateChangeStart. When you open the object in the console, every fields are dynamic so you see the new value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are listening on the `$stateChangeStart` event, the `$location.path()` is still the current path and not the path where it goes to.

You should verify on the `toState` argument.